# Как проверить была нажата буква или нет? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

В процессе разработки столкнулся с потребностью проверки была ли нажата буква(английского/русского алфавита) или же нет.
Изначально, я хотел ее решить конвертированием кода в букву, но этот метод меня не устраивает, т.к. возможно была включена русская раскладка или shift/caps, а буквы будут выводиться только в английском варианте.
Например:`String.fromCharCode(#код)`.Результатом при нажатии на кнопку "f", при русской раскладке будет "F", а нужно "а".

Answer (score 1):

У символа F и а совершенно разные коды символов.
https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events
Тут есть заготовка для проверки эвентов нажатие на клавиатуру.
И при keypress "а" русской, выводится код 1072, а при f - 102.

```
keydown keyCode=70 which=70 charCode=0 char=F
keypress keyCode=1072 which=1072 charCode=1072 char=а
```

Прослушивайте keypress и сравнивайте символы.

Comment: Так это получается мне чекер придется писать под всю раскладку русскую??

Comment: Приведите пример, я не совсем понимаю ,что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Мне нужно получать не символ, а 1)True или False - если это буква или нет(соответственно) 2)Какая это буква конкретно, а не символ на клавиатуре

Comment: Тогда вам придется создать что-то подобие словаря, массив со всеми символами русского языка, а потом через array.includes проверять соответствие.
Можете так же сделать еще проще. Прослушивать keypress, получать код, трансформировать в символ, потом через regexp выражение проверять находится ли она в русской раскладке.
Типо /[аА-яЯ]/.text(convertedChar)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes